# Cannot pass data to database with JSON ajax?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

1 Ajax (Working able to send data to db)

```
 var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();

  ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
          alert(ajax.responseText);
            //window.location.replace('login_form.php');
          }
         };

          ajax.open("POST","register.php",false);
          ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          ajax.send(parameters);
          } // End of else statement
      } // End of function
```

2 JSON AJAX (not Working - data are not sent to my db)

```
 var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();

   ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
   if(ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
    var passData = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);

      }
     };

      ajax.open("POST","register.php",false);
      ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
      ajax.send(parameters);

       } // End of else statement
     } // End of function
```

a) With ajax when i click on my btn register my data is being sent to my database but with json it does not working (both of them show no error).

b) I'm not able to re-direct the user to the login form even after a successful registration, it just remain on the registration page

Comment: in the non-working one, did you make sure that `parameters` is JSON, and in php to read/parse the raw input (`php://input`) since php does not automatically parse JSON request payloads

Comment: Could you clarify what do to mean by making sure that the "parameters" is JSON?                                                                                                         var parameters="firstname="+firstname+"&lastname="+lastname+"&regis_username="+username+"&regis_pass="+password+"&cpass="+confirm_password+"&phone_num="+telephone+"&inputEmail="+email;

Comment: Well you have `"Content-type", "application/json"`, so you have to make sure the content you are sending is JSON, eg `parameters = '{"key":"value"}';` not `'key=value&key2=value2'`